# What's wrong with my Code [Iteration Structure]

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to have an array that contains values of each character of a key typed and I was getting errors. Therefore, I took a very tiny snippet and did lots of tries to see what was going on:

```
for (var j = 0; j < code.length; j++) {
  var UnitPlace = codeLength - j;

  if (code[j] = "0") {
    value = 0;
    encryption.push(0);
  }

  else {
    if (code[j] = "1") {
      value = 1;
      encryption.push(1);
    }

    else {
      if (code[j] = "2") {
        value = 2;
        encryption.push(2);
      }

      else {
        if (code[j] = "3") {
          value = 3;
          encryption.push(3);
        }

        else {
          if (code[j] = "4") {
            value = 4;
            encryption.push(4);
          }

          else {
            if (code[j] = "5") {
              value = 5;
              encryption.push(5);
            }

            else {
              if (code[j] = "6") {
                value = 6;
                encryption.push(6);
              }

              else {
                if (code[j] = "7") {
                  value = 7;
                  encryption.push(7);
                }

              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

document.write(encryption);
```

I was able to realize that only the first if statement is read in the iteration sequence. but the source code you see above is after i realized this and tried having it read the other parts of the sequence but it still reads only the first if statement.

Could someone tell me how to solve it and/or what the problem with my code is?

Comment: `=` is assignment, not comparison

Comment: ...in javascript `=` means "assignment", `==` is the binary compare operator (considers value only) and `===` ...considers value&type...so maybe you didn't want "to assign"(in your if statements), but rather compare!?;)

Comment: Also as a side note; repeated `if (){} else { if(){} }` can be reduced to `if(){}else if(){}`

Comment: All those `if`s can be narrowed down to simple assignments: `value  = +code[j]; encryption.push(+code[j]);` ... But the basic problem is, that at the end of the loop `value` will always contain the last assigned value. What is the desired value at the end of the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this? :

```js
let strCode = "1234567";
let encryption = strCode.split('').map(c => parseInt(c));

document.write(encryption);
```

Comment: also the suggestion code isn't needed, but strCode.split('').map(c => parseInt(c)); is something i've never seen before